# How do I pass in the array output of SQL query into a PostgreSQL (PL/pgSQL) function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, plpgsql

I am able to do the following in SQL where an "array" of user_ids are passed into the `where` clause of a SQL query.

```
select * from users where id in (select user_id from profiles);
```

I would like to do the same thing but pass the "array" into a PostgreSQL (PL/pgSQL) function as shown below. How do I declare the function and work with the "array" within the function?

```
select * from users_function(select user_id from profiles);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION users_function(....)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get the nate c's `array_agg` approach as I described above. This is an option:

```
select * from test_array('{1,2}');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_array(user_ids integer[])
  RETURNS void AS
$$
declare
begin
FOR i in array_lower(user_ids, 1) .. array_upper(user_ids, 1) LOOP
  RAISE NOTICE '%', user_ids[i]::integer;
END LOOP;
end
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare an array datatype `[]` in the function then use the aggregate function `array_agg` to transform the select statement into an array.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION users_function(myints integer[])
$$
 BEGIN
      -- you need to find the bounds with array_lower and array_upper
  FOR i in array_lower(myints, 1) .. array_upper(myints, 1) LOOP
     Raise Notice '%', myints[i]::integer;
  END LOOP;
 END;
$$

select * from users_function(array_agg((select user_id from profiles)));
```

Comment: I'm running PostgreSQL 8.4.4 and getting this error. Any ideas? select array_agg(select id from users limit 2);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"

Comment: Add another set of brackets like: `select array_agg((select id from users limit 2))`. Forgot that - any time you have a subquery in a function you need two sets: one for the function an one for the subquery.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but this is what I got: select array_agg((select id from users limit 2));
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression